# i get the same layout items in second layout of fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

i have app with blank drawer menu and i wont to add tabs , but then i add tabs something goes wrong i now that i made mistake, becouse my first tab layout item shows in second tab layout , i can't find where is the mistake this is my content_main layout xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_main">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

this is how in main activity i add tabs

```
  viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

and this

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Fragment1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Fragment2");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}



class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

plz show my where i made mistake thaks((

this is my first fragment

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

```
private View rootView;

public Fragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if(rootView==null){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }
    return rootView;

}
```

and xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ebebeb">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="13.3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="11dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_clock"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="С 12:00 по 17:00"
            android:textColor="@color/backapuyt" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Your loooooong scrolling content here. -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
    app:bb_behavior="shy"/>
```

this is my second fragment

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {



private ListView mylistView;
private View rootView;
private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
private Request request;
private static ArrayList<OrderModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
private BoxAdapter boxAdapter;
private ListView lvMain;



public Fragment2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if(rootView==null){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vse_zakazi, container, false);
    }
    BottomNavigation();
    mylistView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    fillAllListWithData();
    return rootView;


}


private void BottomNavigation() {

    BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
    bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {

        }
    });
}
```

and this is xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ebebeb">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="13.3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="11dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_clock"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="С 12:00 по 17:00"
            android:textColor="@color/backapuyt" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Your loooooong scrolling content here. -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
    app:bb_behavior="shy"/>
```

Comment: post your fragment code please

Comment: @JonathanAste i edit in my question

Comment: I will not post this as an answer because I'm not sure what's the solution yet. First , the tab layout inflates correctly and you see the 2 tabs ? what do you see in the first tab ? your fragment1 is shown in the second tab?. Try changing your getSupportFragmentManager() to getChildFragmentManager(). Then, move the views initialization (like your listview) from OnCreateView to OnViewCreated method. Let me know if you can fix it.

Comment: @JonathanAste the apps open for test in first page i see the second fragment items